# .Net solution or IDE problem

Tags: .net

I have a weird situation with .Net.
I have 3 different projects
 - 1st is Main server project.
 - 2nd is the Communication class which uses Sockets to communicate with server.
 - 3rd is the Client application.
Everything works fine in Windows 7 but when it comes to Win xp it behaves abnormaly.

My client application sends sometime messages to server thru communcation project and doesnt recevies at all but server do send the messages.
But if I make a new project and copy all the code and files only for client application then it works 100% fine from IDE. That means from IDE If I run the newly made client application in debug or release mode it communicates fine.
But the moment instead of starting from IDE if i start the exe from debug or release folder everythign stops working even from IDE that means server sometimes gets the messages and client never receives the messages from server.
But If I make a new project it works fine only from IDE.
But everything works from windows 7 even from IDE or from direct exe.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should check the project's settings to ensure that nothing is being specified based off of the Windows 7 machine. One thing that Visual Studio does not seem to handle well is switching between x86 and x64 machines. Ensure that x86 is select for CPU Type if that's what is intended.

There could be other issues at play here, but the CPU type is the most common issue I have had with Visual Studio when going between Windows 7 and Windows XP.